# create hexagon design dynamically using css and js

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-shapes

**This is not duplicate of any please help me**

I got some trick here http://jsfiddle.net/kizu/bhGn4/

I want to create it dynamically with `CSS` , so how to do that?

whenever any new entry added to design that adjust automatically.

I have tried hard to search and i got some help for circle shape at here

[How to create circles around a circle with css, javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16613809/how-to-create-circles-around-a-circle-with-css-javascript)

same something I want with hexagon

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how you want the design to adjust. Perhaps a sequence of pictures with numbered hexagons could be of assistance. (ex: pic1 has 3 hexagons, pic2 has 4 hexagons, pic3 has 10 hexagons)

Comment: This is already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062887/generate-repeating-hexagonal-pattern-with-css3

Comment: @Stuart yes i checked that but i want in different direction as you can see in my question's image

Comment: This question features a responsive grid of hexagons in the direction you need : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26114920/responsive-grid-of-hexagons-with-img-tag

Answer (score 2):

Go through this demo which I've created:

```css
.hexagon {
  width: 100px;
  height: 55px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
}
.hexagon:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -25px;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 25px solid red;
}
.hexagon:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -25px;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-top: 25px solid red;
}
.hex1 {
  top: 20px;
  left: 0px;
}
.hex2 {
  top: 20px;
  left: 110px;
}
.hex3 {
  top: 20px;
  left: 220px;
}
.hex4 {
  top: 110px;
  left: 55px;
}
.hex5 {
  top: 110px;
  left: 165px;
}
.hex6 {
  top: 110px;
  left: 275px;
}
```

```html
<div style="position:absolute; top:30px">
  <div class="hexagon hex1"></div>
  <div class="hexagon hex2"></div>
  <div class="hexagon hex3"></div>
  <div class="hexagon hex4"></div>
  <div class="hexagon hex5"></div>
  <div class="hexagon hex6"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks hari , here if i will add another two or three shapes then need to create css for those all ?

Comment: You can add Jquery/Javascript to populate this logic dynamically. So this javascript will do the layout manipulation dynamically. So basically it will act like a plugin. So no need of writing such big css code for doing so(suppose your layout contains 1000 hexagons, it will be 1000 different CSS).

Comment: exactly , i want same-things here, if you can help me will appreciate

Comment: up-voted your answer but if possible please try to make it dynamic

Answer (score 0):

There is a great tutorial here on creating hexagonal shapes with CSS. Check out the step-by step guide at the start.

[Create Hexagon shapes with pure CSS3](http://www.queness.com/post/13901/create-beautiful-hexagon-shapes-with-pure-css3)

Also see this examples on CSSTricks. You'll get an idea of how to approach these kind of problems.

[Shapes of CSS](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/)

Hope that helps! :)

Comment: Superb buddy, its awesome

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this CSS hexagon tutorial](http://creative-punch.net/2014/01/perfect-css-hexagons-size-using-transform-calc/) which describes how to create hexagon shapes AND be able to resize them using calc().

All you need is one value for the height and the rest is done for you. It also uses only a single class