# How to create a big circle with small circle around its border

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I needed to create something like this

[image: A circle with small circles on its border]

I needed to do this with plain HTML, CSS and JavaScript (perhaps) and data inside the small circles are retrieved through PHP. The placement of the mini-circles are dynamic depending on the number of data being retrieved from the database.

Furthermore, it should be responsive as well, since I am going to integrate it with Bootstrap for mobile-friendly site.

Comment: Corner? On a circle? I think not :-)

Comment: Sorry about that. You are right. Circles don't have a corner.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create circles around a circle with css, javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16613809/how-to-create-circles-around-a-circle-with-css-javascript)

Comment: @joelmdev, please see my answer below. I used a JavaScript library called Moon Map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after thorough research, I've found this Stackoverflow question: [How to create circles around a circle with css, javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16613809/how-to-create-circles-around-a-circle-with-css-javascript)

And one of its answer is being integrated into a JavaScript library called [Moon Map](https://github.com/mitch-seymour/moonmap).

[image: An example of an implementation of Moon Map]

I think I am going to use Moon Map for this. And I'll just update my answer after everything goes well. This Moon Map [Documentation](http://moonmapjs.com/docs) and [Examples](http://moonmapjs.com/examples) will definitely be useful.

Comment: The time difference between your question and answer is nonexistent. If you're wanting your question to be a guide, 1) there are methods for that, and 2) just wait until you've actually finished the answer.

Comment: You don't have to delete your answer, but as it is almost an exact answer to your question....